# How to create a rate and comment system for android app?

Tags: java, android, sql, java-server

I want to create a rate system for an android application using java.

Ive searched around and havent found much on the web concerning this.

What do i need to do to build or get started building a rate system for a android application.

Such as the android market. The user is allowed to leave comments and rate a app.

I want to implement the same concept except with the ability just to rate or vote up a object in my application.

Has anyone implemented this before?

Some guidance on this would be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: you need a server and a database to hold all these ratings.  create a script(php perhaps) to manage the ratings on a webserver you own. send requests to said script and have it update the database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pretty broad question, but I would use an approach like this:

`Android Client <--> (RESTful) Web Service (e.g. PHP) <--> Database (e.g. MySQL)`

The last two items, of course, reside server side in this architecture.

The flow would essentially consist of the user makes a rating or comment, an HTTP request is made to your web service, the web service executes a SQL statement that adds the rating or comment to the database, which leads to a result and an HTTP response from which you can update your Android client.

I would first suggest looking into RESTful web services and web services in general if you're unfamiliar with them.

Comment: Thanks for your response this sounds like a great way. What do you think about this  http://www.cn-java.com/download/data/book/socket_chat.pdf Is there anyway i could do this with the example in the link?

Comment: There's definitely more than one way to do this, but ultimately you will need a central database from which all of the Android clients will communicate with (i.e. server side). I think using a web service is generally the best approach, however. Good luck!

Comment: Would goog app engine be considered a webservice? such as http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingdatastore.html